# How to add variable Image on User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, dependency-properties

I'm trying to have a user control where an image is passed in from its containing element.  The purpose is so that I can reuse a common set of visual elements while only changing the image.  For example:

The control usage:

```
<DataTemplate DataType={x:Type myType}>
    <local:MyControl PlotIconSource="..\Images\Scatter.png"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The Image inside the control

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl">
    <Image Source="{Binding PlotIconSource}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Finally the dependency property for PlotIconSource in the code-behind for MyControl.xaml.cs.

```
    public ImageSource PlotIconSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(PlotIconSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PlotIconSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PlotIconSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "PlotIconSource", 
            typeof(ImageSource), 
            typeof(PlotHeader), 
            new UIPropertyMetadata());
```

I'm sure I've missed something along the way so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to bind via [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx) or with [`ElementName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx):

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl" Name="control">
    <Image Source="{Binding PlotIconSource, ElementName=control}"/>
</UserControl>
```

(Do not set the `DataContext`, it will be invisible from the outside and mess with bindings meant for an inherited `DataContext`)

Comment: I tried <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlotIconSource}"/> to no avail; however, using the ElementName approach worked.  Any idea how to do it without ElementName?

Comment: RelativeSource worked with `Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=PlotIconSource}"` the problem was that `Self` was referring to the `Image` rather than the containing `UserControl`.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You're  welcome, glad it helped. Well, when i said relative source that is exactly what i meant, i thought it was apparent...

Answer (score 0):

Looks right to me, are you getting an error message or something?

Comment: I'm getting "System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'PlotIconSource' property not found on 'object' ''ScatterPlotViewModel' (HashCode=40544074)'. BindingExpression:Path=PlotIconSource; DataItem='ScatterPlotViewModel' (HashCode=40544074); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')"

Comment: ahh, of course ... the data context/binding was the missing element